# Applet Security blocking creation of png file

Tags: java, file, security, applet

Hi I have an applet that creates a graph based on some survey data in a CSV file. I want the Applet to also generate a png file of the graph. This works when testing on my computer but when hosted online I get the following security error

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
    ("java.io.FilePermission" "detail.png" "delete")
```

with detail.png being the name of the png file i'm trying to create.

Here's the code that creates the file in my applet.

```
public void imgPaint(){
    done=1;
    setSize(800,500);
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    paint(g2);
    try{ImageIO.write(bi,"png",new File("detail.png"));}catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

So when the applet calls upon the JPanel it goes to the paint method, paints to the screen, then calls this method to paint again to the png file. Anyway the issue doesn't seem to be the code but that Java isn't allowing me to create a png file. It should go to the file I have on the server where the program is hosted.

I really know nothing about Java security so any help you guys could give would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It should go to the file I have on the server where the program is hosted.

For the security of the server, a client (applet or otherwise) cannot make a `File` on the server.  You might provide a specific upload facility (e.g. FTP based) that the applet might then utilize.

That code would actually be attempting to make a `File` on the local file system of the user.

Comment: that makes sense. should of thought of that. Thank you

Comment: do you know of way i could edit an already existing file into a png?

Comment: *"already existing file"*  Not to get around either server side or client side security.